# GitHub API: Can I get the network diagram of git branches to a separate dashboard

Tags: reactjs, git, github, chart.js, github-api

I am developing a dashboard which illustrate some of the details about the git repositories, I have a requirement of getting the network diagram of the git branches as shown here.[image] 
Is there a way to do it? . I am developing the project using React.js and chart.js .